# Calculate first/second variation of the functional $f : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $y \rightarrow \sin(y(1))$

Tags: derivatives, calculus-of-variations, gateaux-derivative

Hey I have a problem with this exercise.

I have to calculate the first and second variation of the functional $f : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$y \rightarrow \sin(y(1))$ for $V = C^0([a, b])$ with $a < 1 < b$

I have used the definition and I have done the following:

$δf |_y(a)=\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(y+ay)-f(y)}{a}=\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(y(1)+ay(1))-\sin(y(1))}{a}$

But now I don't know how to proceed. Can someone help me?

Comment: You do realise that $y(1)$ is a constant according to your formulation ?

Comment: Yes, so I have: $δf |_y(a)=\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(y(1)+ay(1))-\sin(y(1))}{a}=\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}(\frac{\sin(y(1)+ay(1))}{a}-\frac{\sin(y(1))}{a})=\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}(\frac{\sin(y(1)+ay(1))}{a})$ Is the result $0$?

Comment: The value of $\sin(y(1))$ IS a constant. What happens when you derive a constant w.r.t to a variable ?

Comment: so it is equal to $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(y(1)+ay(1))}{a}=\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{y(1)\cos(y(1)+ay(1))}{1}=y(1)\cos(y(1))$, right?

Comment: Your definition of the [first variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation) is doubly incorrect: there shouldn't be $a$ on the left side of $=\lim_{a\to0},$ and on the right side $a$ should be multiplied by some other function instead of $y.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation) and [second](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Second_variation) variations of $f$ are given by
$$\begin{align}\delta f(y,h)&=\left.\frac d{da}f(y+ah)\right|_{a=0}\\&=\left.\frac d{da}\sin(y(1)+ah(1))\right|_{a=0}\\&=\left.h(1)\cos(y(1)+ah(1))\right|_{a=0}\\&=h(1)\cos y(1)\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}\delta^2f(y,h)&=\left.\frac{d^2}{da^2}f(y+ah)\right|_{a=0}\\&=\left.\frac d{da}h(1)\cos(y(1)+a h(1))\right|_{a=0}\\&=\left.-h^2(1)\sin(y(1)+ah(1))\right|_{a=0}\\&=-h^2(1)\sin y(1).\end{align}$$